# Elasticsearch aggregation query not giving expected output

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to do aggregation on documents which contains datetime and CPU time and server name. I want to find the avg CPU time on latest date. I have the following query which partially works it gives me the avg CPU time but not on latest date it just randomly chooses date.

```
client.prepareSearch("myindex").
       setTypes("mytype").
       setQuery(
           QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),
           FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.termFilter("server","x")))).
       addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.avg("cpu_agg")
           .field("dt_time").field("cpu_time"))
       .get()
```

Please guide. I want avg cpu time on latest date say today's date. I am new to ElasticSearch. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kinda strange search request. Why do you use andfilter with only one clause? And it is kind of deprecated - use boolfilter instead. Why do you provide two fields to avg aggregation? AFAIK it needs only one. If you want avg only for specified date use range filter on dt_time

Comment: yep, you should move your dt_time into the filtering part (i.e. remove it from aggregation and add another filter, that filters on latest date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   client.prepareSearch("myindex").
   setTypes("mytype").
   setQuery(
       QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),
       FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.termFilter("server","x")))).
   addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.avg("cpu_agg")
       .field("dt_time").field("cpu_time"))
   .get()
```

look at the portion (where field is set to dt_time at first and replaced to cpu_time), which means aggregation is build for  cpu_time,

If you want to get cpu time in today's date then one way is use date filter ,

```
       FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.termFilter("server","x"),FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("dt_time").to(to).from(from))))
```

For your problem, from = to = today_date (or last date)

so finally,

```
client.prepareSearch("myindex").
                setTypes("mytype").
                setQuery(
                        QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),
                                FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.termFilter("server", "x"), FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("dt_time").to("to").from("from")))).
                addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.avg("cpu_agg")
                        .field("cpu_time"))
                .get();
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the reply. How do I give input date if I dont know in advance. I want something like select max(date) from table;

Comment: You cannot feed a result of one (metric) aggregation to another, If you have to do max(date), then execute aggregation to get max date to get date, and do another aggregation for cpu_time.

Comment: Hi I tried to use Aggregation.max("dt_time_agg").field("dt_time") but it does not give me max date it somehow converts date into double exponential value. It would be great help if you help me find the max/latest date from documents.

Comment: You can ask a separate question for this, I or any-other can answer and find it useful.

Comment: I found solution max aggregation returns double which needs to be converted into long and then to datetime.

Comment: Yes, In our company we only use long for date (in indexing), so manipulation is always necessary.